# JS New Date() returns epoch 0

Tags: javascript, datetime

JS application

node v10.16.3

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ava": "^2.4.0",
    "bluemix-autoscaling-agent": "^1.0.14",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.12",
    "cfenv": "^1.2.1",
    "loopback": "^3.19.3",
    "loopback-boot": "^3.1.0",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^6.0.1",
    "loopback-connector-redis": "git+https://github.com...redis.git",
    "newrelic": "^4.1.4",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nyc": "^14.1.0",
    "proxyquire": "^2.0.1",
    "sinon": "^5.0.10",
    "standard": "^10.0.2"
  }
```

Problem:

```
new Date() returns 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

and

```
Date.now() returns 0
```

Expected: Current date and time for `new Date()` in following logic:

```
if (new Date(oldDate) <= new Date()) {
  // this never happens!
}
```

Happens only in runtime. edited. npm test

If I start node and type new Date() it will return current date and time.

```
> new Date()
2020-01-31T07:53:16.747Z
```

Any ideas what to check!

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue in the same version of node. It's always returning the current date and time. Can you be more specific with steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Well it is specific to a certain machine. In other environments I can't reproduce it. I posted this because I have no idea and hoped that someone have faced this same issue. Did not find anything by google. Maybe I need to recreate development environment and see if it get fixed.

Comment: If you can recreate it then it'll be easier to possibly provide insight into the problem.  If you are able to reproduce it on any machine then post the steps and we can try help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was Sinon fake timer that is on by default. I disabled it and new Date() works like expected.

```
sinon.createSandbox(sinon.defaultConfig.useFakeTimers = false)
```